# Don't permit to display saved password on eyeIcon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I've got registration form where user can show his password when click on an eye icon.

The thing is that I don't want to permit to display saved password in an edit page (saved password from the browser's keychain) if it hasn't been directly typed or at all. Is it possible to disable this in such case?

```
eyeIcon.click(function(evt) {
  var eye = $(this),
      field = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield'),
      isInTextMode = field.attr('type') == 'text';

  // update field and icon view

  if (!isInTextMode) {
    field.attr('type', 'text');
    eye.attr('src', eyeIconSrc.active);
  }
  else {
    field.attr('type', 'password');
    eye.attr('src', eyeIconSrc.inactive);
  }
});
```

**Edit**

To be more clarify: the user (or their worst enemy) can freely recover a previously saved password from the browser's keychain and then clicking on the eye button, they can see the plain password, exposing a vulnerability, especially if they use the same password for everything - please take a look [here](https://monosnap.com/file/Kdc9XO9ZRWtDVg83XzE6gPpQgOjWTR)

I want to allow user to show his password using `eyeIcon` only when it's typed directly from the browser, and don't permit when it's provided as on the link above.

Comment: Passwords should be saved as secure hashes, not plaintext

Comment: Ok but probably this will not solve my problem, am I right?

Comment: Well there's no reason for already hashed and saved passwords to ever be sent back to the client anyway; it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hm, ok maybe I wasn't too clarify, please take a look for my update

Comment: The user's worst enemy can always use the browser console to see the `<input>` value whether it's visible on the screen or not.

Comment: @Pointy maybe this is a little bit silly but well, the app requires it

Answer (score 0):

Cool question, thank you. Addressing specifically this question of making the password entry field plain text visible with the eye icon action, have you considered not rendering the eye icon (and associated JS that you show) when it isn't appropriate?

That strategy would require some adjustment of your views, particularly if you use a form partial for create (where you want the behavior) and edit (where you don't).

One way is to put conditional logic in the partial. Another is to decompose the form partial into re-used parts, and render different partials (that reuse parts) for create and edit.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I don't want to edit my views because this is quite big app and it require a lot of updates which will be worst case scenario for me. I was hoping to find easier solution for that.

Comment: What the OP is asking is how to keep the password hidden when the *browser* fills it in based on the user's collection of saved passwords. It cannot be *truly* hidden in that case, and there might be no 100% reliable way to tell that the password has indeed been auto-filled (esp. a way that doesn't risk hiding the password from somebody who *should* be able to see it).

Comment: Ok but you think it is impossible to tell if the password was entered automatically or entered by the user? if the browser has that type of providing data (auto-filled) we should be able to recognize it.